# add a calculation text in every facet in R with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to add an operation (division) in the right corner at the top of every facet. I need to divide value of z by value of x for A, B, C.
for A the operation result is 0.17 (400/2300), for B is 0.1363(30/200) and for C is 0.10 (2/19)

I was going to use annotate, but I read to better use geom_text  when using facet

```
         dt<-data.frame(va=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3), rep("C",3))
                         ,vb=c(rep(letters[24:26],3))
                         ,value=c(23*100,13*100,4*100,22*10,12*10,3*10,19,8,2))

    ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=vb,y=value)) +
    geom_col(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
    facet_wrap(~va,scales="free_y")+
    geom_text(aes(label=value))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new dataframe in which you calculate the result you want to display, as well as the x, y position. Then you can change the dataframe used by the `geom_text` layer with the `data` argument.

```
dt_calc <- dt %>%
  pivot_wider(va, vb) %>%
  mutate(result = z / x, xpos = "z", ypos = pmax(x, y, z))

ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = vb, y = value)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap( ~ va, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_text(aes(x = xpos, y = ypos, label = round(result, 2)), data = dt_calc)
```

Output:

[image: graph]

Comment: I am using this logic with other data, but it doesn't work because of the name of the variables. once I use the same name for x, y in geom_text, it worked. why this could be for? in your example for y you have "ypos" and the name of origin is "value". what would be the difference between this example data and my actual work data. thanks

Comment: Maybe. You'll have to update your question with the variable names that you are having a problem with